# prove this trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

If $$\tan \theta +\sin \theta =m $$
and
  $$\tan \theta -\sin \theta =n$$
then prove that $$m^2-n^2=4\sqrt{mn}$$

I've  tried to $(m^2-n^2)$ as $(m-n)(m+n)$ but can't get to RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: note that
$$
mn = (\tan\theta+\sin\theta)(\tan\theta-\sin\theta) = \tan^2\theta-\sin^2\theta
$$
Which can then be written as
$$
\tan^2\theta-\sin^2\theta = \sin^2\theta\left(\sec^2\theta-1\right)
$$
Continue from there, using some trig identities.

Comment: Now i'll complete it